# Writing a list append function in OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I've defined a custom list type as part f a homework exercise.

```
type 'a myType =
  | Item of ('a * 'a myType)
  | Empty;;
```

I've already done 'length' and now I need a 'append' function.
My length function:

```
let length l =
  let rec _length n = function
    | Empty         -> n
    | Item(_, next) -> _length (n + 1) next
  in _length 0 l;;
```

But I really don't know how to make the append function.

```
let append list1 list2 = (* TODO *)
```

I can't use the list module so I can't use either `::` or `@`.

Comment: This is obviously a homework problem.  Here are my hints: (a) you can define your function so that the second parameter appears unchanged in the result.  So you really just need to worry about the first parameter.  (b) If you think recursively, you only need to know how to append to an empty list, and how to break a non-empty list down into a smaller append problem (i.e., one with a shorter list).  I hope this helps, but not too much!  Regards,

Comment: My problem is how can I append two elements? Should I have to use ":="? Thanks!!

Comment: You should think of creating a *new* list, not of appending the old lists.  However, the second list can appear unchanged in the new list.  If you had a list `Item (3, Empty)` and you wanted to add `4` to the beginning, what would the result look like?

Comment: I think it looks like `Item (4, Item (3, Empty))`

Comment: Yes.  Note that the old list is in there, it still looks the same.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is how to create a new Item? I think I don't really understand..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess my comments are getting too lengthy to count as mere comments.  I don't really want to answer, I just want to give hints.  Otherwise it defeats the purpose.

To repeat my hints:

a.  The second parameter will appear unchanged in your result, so you can just
    spend your time worrying about the first parameter.

b.  You first need to know how to append something to an empty list.  I.e., you need
    to know what to do when the first parameter is Empty.

c.  You next need to know how to break down the non-empty case into a smaller append
    problem.

If you don't know how to create an item, then you might start by writing a function that takes (say) an integer and a list of integers and returns a new list with the integer at the front.  Here is a function that takes an integer and returns a list containing just that one integer:

```
let list1 k =
    Item (k, Empty)
```

One way to think of this is that every time `Item` appears in your code,  you're creating a new item.  `Item` is called a *constructor* because it constructs an item.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your structure is a list, so you should start by defining a value `nil` that is the empty list, and a function `cons head tail`, that appends the `head` element in front of the list `tail`.

Another advice: sometimes, it helps a lot to start by taking a simple example, and trying to do it *manually*, i.e. decomposing what you want to do in simple operations that you do yourself. Then, you can generalize and write the code...